# Access to array's indexPath in a function Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, indexpath

I am trying to **access an array's `indexPath`** inside a function to **update this array's data** but I don't know how to pass the `indexPath` as a parameter (espacially what to pass when calling) to the function or if this is even the solution.

I included `cellForRowAt` to **illustrate** how this function access `indexPath`.

```
var cryptosArray: [Cryptos] = []

extension WalletTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CryptoCellDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let crypto = cryptosArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell
        cell.setCrypto(crypto: crypto)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

         if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
            return
        }
        let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

        let crypto = cryptosArray[indexPath.row] //<---- How to do that?

        crypto.amount = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

        //Then update array's amount value at correct index


        walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

    }


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of hacking something, simply ask the `tableView` to tell you the `indexPath` of the given cell:

```
// use indexPath(for:) on tableView
let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: walletTableViewCell)

// then you can simply use it
let crypto = cryptosArray[indexPath.row]
```

`UITableView.indexPath(for:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614881-indexpath) says:

> Returns an index path representing the row and section of a given table-view cell.

And this is exactly what you want, you don't want to hack the `indexPath` to the cell. `indexPath` should be taken care of by the `tableView`, not the cell. Ideally, cell should be completely oblivious of its `indexPath`.

Always try to use the standard way to solve your problems. In general, when you are trying to solve something, I would recommend you to first look at the documentation of the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview), there are many useful methods there.

Comment: Once again I have nothing to add except this is the perfect answer Milan, I wish I could take classes from you!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get index path.row when user clicked on cell , you should get index path.row when user clicked and then use this to your func

for ex :

```
var indexrow : int = 0
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // table cell clicked
       indexrow = indexPath.row
    }

func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

     if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
        return
    }
    let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

    let crypto = cryptosArray[indexrow] 

    crypto.amount = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text

    //Then update array's amount value at correct index


    walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

}
```